# How to plot the following barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a bar plot for following data.

```
  year  fips  Emissions   
1 1999 06037 68.4060000  
2 2002 06037 78.0598486    
3 2005 06037 85.7657985  
4 2008 06037 85.1871200  
5 1999 24510  0.5600000  
6 2002 24510 10.5183944  
7 2005 24510 10.2240684  
8 2008 24510  0.4772056
```

Here `fips` and `year` are factors.

I tried the following code in ggplot2

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(year, Emissions, fill=fips))
g + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge()) + 
  labs(title = "Comparative pollution levels in San Fransisco and Baltimore", 
       x = "Year", xlab = unique(df$year)) + 
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("San Fransisco", "Baltimore"), values = c("#999999", "#E69F00")) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  guides(color = guide_legend("Counties"))
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

I am also not able to change the names in the legend in spite of adding code for it.

How do I plot it using the base plotting system? I was able to plot it using ggplot2 using following code.

Comment: Please properly format your question.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to the platform, also I didn't have privilege to add inline image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `aes` call you used the `fill` arg. So to edit the behavior of that `fill` you can use `scale_fill_manual` instead of `scale_color_manual` (which would edit the behavior of whatever was passed to the `color` arg in `aes`).

I'm assuming your last line of code using `guides` was meant to edit the legend title.  In the below code I edit the title using `name` in `scale_fill_manual`.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.table(text="  year  fips  Emissions   
                       1 1999 06037 68.4060000  
                       2 2002 06037 78.0598486    
                       3 2005 06037 85.7657985  
                       4 2008 06037 85.1871200  
                       5 1999 24510  0.5600000  
                       6 2002 24510 10.5183944  
                       7 2005 24510 10.2240684  
                       8 2008 24510  0.4772056", header=T)
df$year <- factor(df$year)
df$fips <- factor(df$fips)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(year, Emissions, fill=fips))
g + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge()) + 
  labs(title = "Comparative pollution levels in San Fransisco and Baltimore", 
       x = "Year", xlab = unique(df$year)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Counties",
                    labels = c("San Fransisco", "Baltimore"), 
                    values = c("#999999", "#E69F00")) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]